# MythicMobs: How to set a custom name for a disguised entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-spigot

i've got stuck on my SCP Project, i'm just making projects with MythicMobs but i got stuck with this:

```
Mob_131-1:
  Type: rabbit
  Display: '1311'
  Health: 75
  Damage: 1
  Options:
      Despawn: false
      MovementSpeed: 0.3
      Silent: true
  Disguise:
      Type: BABY_ZOMBIE
      Player: '&f&lSCP-131' <-- #This thing
```

I'm trying to discover how i can set a custom name for SCP-131, but all i found was talking about Player disguises. i want to stay with this

```
  Display: '1311'
```

Because i'll use it for a condition to 173 to stop.
So i need a custom name for the mob to make it look decorated, but a name like the Display which will work with the command block functions.

Comment: Please only use bold to emphasize your text, not as a font style to use in the whole post! I've fixed it for you, no biggie :)